# SEO and new site - visibility best practices

Tags: seo, analytics, pagerank, visitors

Since i launched a new web site, i was wondering which are the best practices to let the visibility of the site grow up faster then just leaving the site online?

I mean which internet channels are good to speed up visibility of a new site?
Can anyone show some tricks he do when launching new site?

I'm not talking about spam, advertising and SEO tech tips (the site is well done with all the main SEO tech tricks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...which internet channels are good to speed up visibility of a new site? Can anyone show some tricks he do when launching new site?

Since you have your advertising and SEO taken care of, you may want to clarify this part of your question. Be as specific as possible.

Generally speaking, if your SEO and advertising is all set, the only thing left to do is promote your site. A few post-launch tricks in my bag are:

1. Regularly scheduled press releases
2. Participate in related forums (concurrently spreading the word of your site)
3. Keep your visitors involved - form a community (e.g. forums, etc.)

This is just a short list until you provide more details of exactly what you hope to accomplish.

Hope that helps!

Comment: well .. as web channels i mean the some of you sad, forums, blogs etc, thanks for your tricks ;)

Comment: You're welcome. You'll find as you move along with your website that there really isn't any magic bullet. It's a compilation of efforts that you make to generate "buzz" about your site. That short list should get you started. Never stop learning! Stick with what works for you and put everything else on the back-burner.

Comment: I agree, my biggest trouble is to avoid spam my links, cause me in first person don't like spam, so it's hard to inform people about a new url web, they always think it's spam :/